# Select within select with multiple matches on the other table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, aggregate-functions, lateral-join

I have these 3 tables
Table 1:

```
 id_Table1  field_table1_1  field_table1_2
       1          A                B
       2          C                D
       3          E                F
```

Table 1:

```
 id_Table2  field_table2_1  field_table2_2
       4          G                H
       5          I                J
```

List item

Table 3:

```
 id_Table3  id_Table1  id_Table2
     1           1          4
     2           1          5
     3           2          5
```

So table 3 holds the relation between table 1 and 2.

What I want to do, is with a query, get all the fields in the table 1, plus one extra field that contains all the ids of the table 2 separated by coma.

So the result should be something like this:

```
 id_Table1  field_table1_1  field_table1_2   id_Table2
       1          A                B            4, 5
       2          C                D             5
       3          E                F
```

Comment: Comma*. A [coma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma) is very different to a comma (`,`).

Comment: totally right! English not my main language lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option use a lateral join and `string_agg()`:

```
select t1.*, x.*
from table1 t1
outer apply (
    select string_agg(t3.id_table2) id_table2
    from table3 t3
    where t3.id_table1 = t1.id_table1
) x
```

There is no need to bring `table2` to get the results you want.